# How to retrieve LDAP user detail (title) using excel VBA (Edirectory not AD)

Tags: excel, ldap, edirectory

I thank you for your time.   I have a 2010 excel document that I would like when a user opens the document gets thier enviornment "user" name and populates a cell on which I would like to use this informatoin to search LDAP for that users "title" We are using Novell Edirectory and not Active Directory but for sure have an LDAP server.

(Maybe its possible to get this information about the user title without the populated "user" field? built into the ldap search of current logged in user not sure the best method.)
(I of course have been all over the net on this one and would just like to start over and say I have nothing to go on.)

Thanks
Wins

Comment: I found this post very helpful, look at marked answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110232/getting-ad-details-based-on-username