# VBA Is there a way in Ms Access to open the Outlook address book and when i click on a name it's go in a form input box?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-office

I make an Access database for a big company, its just for only a few smaller administration thing, but there are thousand of workers and anybody can use it if needed. There are thousands of people in the Outlook address book, and they are changing very fast, so the book refreshing almost every day.

In a form there is an input field where the user can add names, i want to solve that way the user could choose from the outlook address list and when clicking the name filling the form field.

Can you give me any tips?

Comment: The address book is probably based on Active Directory, you might consider reading directly from there. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21113591/3820271

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm).

It offers access to the [AddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm) which should allow you to build a replica listbox using the users Outlook contacts.