# get AD group description

Tags: vba, active-directory

I need a VBA function to return the description of AD groups.

Returning the value with Powershell would be easy:

```
Adgroup = "abc"
strCommand = "Powershell.exe [environment]::CurrentDirectory='C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'; start-job -ScriptBlock{Get-ADGroup -identity " & Adgroup & " -Properties Description | select Description | ft -HideTableHeaders} | wait-job | receive-job"
  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll

Debug.Print strOutput
```

This code returns the correct output, however it has the downside of popping up the PS window.
I found a solution that can hide the PS window, however when I use it, the Antivirus software blocks the script. Since I do not want to mess with it, I need a different solution.

What would be a good non Powershell approach for this?

Comment: You cannot just bypass the antivirus software with code. You would need to disable it manually first.

Comment: @braX I used PS to return values previously into VBA with different scripts. I don't want to disable my AV software. What I need, is a different solution that is not PS. I could return `Get-ADGroup -identity " & Adgroup & " -Properties Description | select Description | ft -HideTableHeaders'`, but as I said, it's not an ideal solution. I need a different solution. This is what I'm asking in my question.

Comment: You may want to include that in your question then. It's always best to show people what you have tried already.

Comment: @braX done. I hope now it's clear what I need

Comment: This Powershell approach is doomed. You can access the AD directly in VBA, the main keyword to search for is "ADSI" (Active Directory Service Interface). Random example https://stackoverflow.com/a/21113591/18771

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Divin3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402297/divin3) and [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) for your valuable discussions. Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Access the AD directly in VBA. You can use ADSI (Active Directory
> Service Interface) for the same.
>
> Reference:
> http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/10/activedirectory-with-vba-part-4-adsi.html,
> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110232/getting-ad-details-based-on-username/21113591#:~:text=LDAP%20URIs%20require,some%20time%20ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110232/getting-ad-details-based-on-username/21113591#:%7E:text=LDAP%20URIs%20require,some%20time%20ago).